# TypeError: category type does not support sum operations (in pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, line-plot, clustermap

I have flight's seaborn dataset.

```py
import seaborn as sns

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights') 
flights.groupby(['year']).sum()
```

when i run this, i get error like :
`TypeError: category type does not support sum operations`

facing this issues in clusteMap and Lineplot

your Assistence will be Appreciated!

Comment: It would help to post a small example of what this dataframe looks like and which columns you'd like to sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet works in pandas 1.* but not in pandas 2.

```py
import seaborn as sns

flights = sns.load_dataset('flights') 
flights.groupby(['year']).sum() # Error
```

The issue is that the `month` column has type `category`:

```py
flights.info(True)
```

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 144 entries, 0 to 143
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column      Non-Null Count  Dtype   
---  ------      --------------  -----   
 0   year        144 non-null    int64   
 1   month       144 non-null    category
 2   passengers  144 non-null    int64   
dtypes: category(1), int64(2)
memory usage: 2.9 KB
```

In pandas 1.*, the `month` column is automatically dropped because its type does not support the `sum` method.

To get to the same result in pandas 2, you'll want to specifically select the `passengers` column (and any other col of interest):

```py
flights.groupby('year')[['passengers']].sum()
```

yields:

```
      passengers
year            
1949        1520
1950        1676
1951        2042
1952        2364
1953        2700
1954        2867
1955        3408
1956        3939
1957        4421
1958        4572
1959        5140
1960        5714
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to convert the year column to a numerical or integer type

```
flights['year'] = flights['year'].astype(int)
result = flights.groupby(['year']).sum()
```

Comment: `year` is an int. `month` is not.